# How to add new lines to Pandas by some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
ID    week    count_tasks

1     3        1
2     3        4
3     4        3
3     5        2
4     28       1
...   ...      ...
7151  21       1
7152  29       1
```

I want to add a new row to the column week attended each `week` from 1 to 53(or from the `week.min()` to a `week.max()`). And if this week no `count_tasks`, the column `count_tasks` will be 0.

Example:

```
ID    week    count_tasks

1     1        0
1     2        0
1     3        1
1     4        0
...   ...      ...
1     53       0
2     1        0
...   ...      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with pivot and then reindex on axis=1 then stack back:

```
week_min = 1 # replace with week.min()
week_max = 53 #replace with week.max()
out = (df.set_index(['ID','week'])['count_tasks'].unstack()
   .reindex(range(week_min,week_max+1),axis=1).stack(dropna=False).fillna(0)
    .reset_index(name='count_tasks'))
print(out)
```

---

#sample output for first 4 IDs (5 rows):

```
     ID  week  count_tasks
0     1     1          0.0
1     1     2          0.0
2     1     3          1.0
3     1     4          0.0
4     1     5          0.0
..   ..   ...          ...
207   4    49          0.0
208   4    50          0.0
209   4    51          0.0
210   4    52          0.0
211   4    53          0.0

[212 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: See. Thanks a lot)

Comment: @MarySmith There was a slight bug, edited my answer 2 mins ago, can you try again please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, a bit more straightforward as it does not use stack/unstack

```py
(df.set_index(['ID', 'week'])
    .reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.ID.unique(), range(df.week.min(), df.week.max() + 1)])
        .set_names(['ID', 'week']),
        fill_value=0)
    .reset_index())
```

`pd.MultiIndex.from_product` will automatically create an index based on all combinations from given lists. I need to use `set_names` to restore column names after resetting index.

---

Result with sample data:

```py
# Data used
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'week': [4, 5, 7, 1, 35, 52], 
    'count_tasks': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
```

```py
      ID  week  count_tasks
0     1     1             0
1     1     2             0
2     1     3             0
3     1     4             1
4     1     5             1
..   ..    ..            ..
99    2    48             0
100   2    49             0
101   2    50             0
102   2    51             0
103   2    52             1
```

As you can see, weeks are ranging from min to max.